# how to get element selector if the div is loading dynamically in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need to run two ajax calls. 2nd call loads some html on the page. But in first call I need to process one div which will not be present there until second call completed. Hence it gives error like selector is null.
What is the solution for this.
Can I change the sequence of two calls.

Comment: What do you mean with "process" one `div` before it's present?

Comment: If you need to process div after second call loads it then process it in callback function of second ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just process in the callback? Like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});
```

Comment: If you really want to manipulate elements inserted from Ajax2 in Ajax1 (before ajax2 completes) i suppose you could do i like so: [link]http://liveweave.com/ME5Cbu but i is not pretty!

Answer (score 1):

you need to check for selector length

like below

```
if($('selector').length){     // selector "ID" or 'Class'
  /// your code
}
```

NOTE : if selector available after second ajax call you can write your code in second ajax call success( callback ) function.